# Инициализация массива в golang, синтаксис

Tags: golang

```
    var arr_1 [5]int
    var arr_2  = [5]int{1,2,3,4,5}
    var arr_3 [5]int = [5]int{5,4,3,2,1}
    //
    fmt.Println("Массив arr_1 содержит элементы : ",arr_1) // 0 0 0 0 0
    fmt.Println("Массив arr_2 содержит элементы : ",arr_2) // 1 2 3 4 5
    fmt.Println("Массив arr_3 содержит элементы : ",arr_3) // 5 4 3 2 1
```

---

```
Знаю про сокращенную форму определения массива
    arr := [5]int{1,2,3,4,5}
Пока хочу понять по приведенному выше через var.
```

По arr_1 : все элементы массива инициализируются значениями по умолчанию, т.е. нулями. Это понял. Не пойму в чем разница между присваиванием в случаях с arr_2 и arr_3. Т.е. по arr_2 : создаем массив длиной 5, с указанными значениями и именем. По arr_3 : создаем массив на пять элементов со значениями по умолчанию (нулями) и указанным именем, а потом вносим новые значения элементов? Объясните, пожалуйста, как правильно делать и в чём разница.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разницы нет. Типизация данных в Golang, компилятор способен сам вывести тип значения [Type inference](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4_%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2)

Comment: Да, о том, что компилятор вычисляет тип, - я читал. Такой вопрос : я  правильно описал выше, что для arr_2 мы создаём массив со значениями; а для arr_3 нулевые значения переназначаем. Не пойму, какой смысл так делать .. а такие примеры есть ...

Comment: Приведенные мною три строчки с var - это всё правильные способы объявления массивов?

Comment: Все правильно вы написали. Я не пойму сути вопроса. Если вопрос в том, выполняется ли излишняя (в данном случае) операция заполнения нулями до присвоения значений... - сложно сказать. Первое - не понятно как вмешаться в этот процесс и зачем. Второе и главное - компилятор в обоих случаях сделает тоже самое! arr_2 и arr_3 идентичны, и даже запись без указания типа предпочтительней.

    var arr_2  = [5]int{1,2,3,4,5}
    var arr_3 [5]int = [5]int{1,2,3,4,5}